# angularjs - have a button click alter another element's content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so the question title is vague but basically I have a button element, I want to click that button and have another element be altered by it. Could anyone give me any idea's on what I'm missing or give me a clear example of how to achieve this.

code below:

html:

```
<div ng-controller="buttonController">
     <button ng-click="fadeIt()">click to fade</button>
     <div class="redbox" my-directive my-two-way-binding="twoWay">fade me</div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
function buttonController($scope){
    $scope.twoWay = false;

    $scope.fadeIt = function(){
        $scope.twoWay = !$scope.twoWay;
        console.log("inside fadeIt function $scope.twoWay is: " + $scope.twoWay);
    }
}
```

directive:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function(){
     return{
         restrict:"A",
         scope: {
             twoWayBind: "=myTwoWayBinding"
         },
         link:function(scope, element, attrs){
             //console.log("directive - twoWayBind is: " + scope.twoWayBind);    
             scope.$watch(scope.twoWayBind, function(newVal){
                 console.log('inside directive ' + scope.twoWayBind);    
             });
         }
     };
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scope.$watch(scope.twoWayBind` should be `scope.$watch('twoWayBind'` because $watch accepts a string referring to a property on scope, not an actual model. Other than that I think you have the right idea.

Also, for cleanliness sake, you could have made it

```
scope:{
  twoWayBind: "=myDirective"
}
```

then you could shorten your template code to:

```
 <div class="redbox" my-directive="twoWay">
```

which in my opinion is a little cleaner.